# Excel. Access single value from array function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a custom function in Excel 2007. It returns array of doubles.

```
Dim ResultArray(10) As Double
```

If I use it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter I get 10 results in a row.

I want to access a particular resut within the result array.

Say second result. I'd expect something like =myFn(a,b,c)(2) but it doesnt work....

Is it possible?

Comment: Is it (2) or [2] .. array syntax is different in any language. Also I think you should try varA = myFn(a,b,c) and then do varA(2) (or varA[2]). Finally, you could write a second function with an extra parameter as index of the double you actually want.

Comment: Actually, myFn(a,b,c)(2) is perfectly valid *VBA* syntax, but as your accepted answer states, the Excel worksheet function to use is INDEX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Index function to get certain element of Array.

```
=Index(myFn(a,b,c); 2)
```

Comment: or maybe comma instead of semicolon?  semicolon works in openoffice

Comment: semicolon is used as separator instead of comma in various locales, especially in Slavic ones