# Array formula, return only 1 specific value

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a question for Excel's Array formula.

I have an array formula that returns  10 different values. If I only want to the 5th value, how do I do this? I believe there is a formula, but i'm not sure what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the INDEX function: {=INDEX(arrayformula,5,1)} or {=INDEX(arrayformula,1,5)} depending whether your array formula returns rows or columns

Comment: Heres what my array formula looks like

`{=xCallableBond(C11,C14,C28:C40,E8:E17,E18:E26,E27:E30,E33,E34,E35,1,INDIRECT(F44))}`

So I just change it to

`{=INDEX(=xCallableBond(C11,C14,C28:C40,E8:E17,E18:E26,E27:E30,E33,E34,E35,1,INDIRECT(F44)), 5, 1}`

Answer (score 0):

a very similar question:
[Excel. Access single value from array function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178310/excel-access-single-value-from-array-function)

short answer: the `=index()` function is what you're looking for.